CSV Helper - Create Numeric column instead of General
I am using CSV Helper to create a CSV file as follows:
for (int i = 0; i < dsData.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DateTime invDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dsData.Rows[i]["DocDate"].ToString());
    string invoiceDate = invDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

    invoices.Add(new Invoices
    {
        Recordtype = "DIALSALES01ZA",
        DistributorCode = 161457,
        InvoiceNumber = dsData.Rows[i]["DocNum"].ToString(),
        InvDate = invoiceDate,
        SCJProductCode = dsData.Rows[i]["CardCode"].ToString(),
        DistributorProductCode = dsData.Rows[i]["CardCode"].ToString(),
        SalesmanCode = dsData.Rows[i]["SlpCode"].ToString(),
        SalesmanName = dsData.Rows[i]["SlpName"].ToString(),
        SupervisorCode = "Kinyanjui",
        SupervisorName = "Kamau",
        WarehouseCode = dsData.Rows[i]["WhsCode"].ToString(),
        WarehouseName = dsData.Rows[i]["WhsName"].ToString(),
        OutletTypeCode = "Mini mart",
        OutletTypeName = "Mini mart",
        ClientInternalCode = dsData.Rows[i]["CardCode"].ToString(),
        ClientFederalID = dsData.Rows[i]["CardCode"].ToString(),
        ClientName = dsData.Rows[i]["CardName"].ToString(),
        City = dsData.Rows[i]["City"].ToString(),
        ZipCode = 0,
        DeliveryAddress = dsData.Rows[i]["Address"].ToString(),
        Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(dsData.Rows[i]["U_PCs"].ToString()),
        GrossValue = Convert.ToDouble(dsData.Rows[i]["GTotal"].ToString()),
        NetValue = Convert.ToDouble(dsData.Rows[i]["LineTotal"].ToString()),
        Fraction = 1,
        EANCode = "1",
    });
}

DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;

Random rnd = new Random();
double num = rnd.Next(1, 10000000);

string filename = dateTimeNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + num.ToString() + ".csv";

var csvPath = "C:/Integrations/RAISONS/SCJohnsonIntegration/Invoices_CSVs/" + filename + "";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(csvPath))
{
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {                            
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(invoices);
    }
}                   
}

It creates the following CSV and you can see the Quantity column is "General". I would like to make this column as "Number". How do I acheve this?


CSV files are not Excel workbooks - and (excepting quoted-strings and raw digit chars), CSV files do not contain column data type information, so it's entirely up to the end-user to tell Excel that a column is Numeric (or General, or Dates, or etc) when they use the Text Import Wizard. If you need more control over your Excel integration then you should create actual .xlsx files instead of .csv files.

Can you show the generated CSV-File? Maybe it works, when you export the numbers without ".

@Dai - understood.

It seems "Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(dsData.Rows[i]["U_PCs"].ToString())" is expressed as a number not a string.

@KinyanjuiKamau Using Convert.ToDouble(dsData.Rows[i]["U_PCs"].ToString()) is not the right way to do this... (namely, Convert.ToDouble should not be used by anyone, IMO: use Double.Parse/TryParse instead; and you don't need .ToString(). CsvHelper supports parsing typed columns quite efficiently using its generic methods.

Is your question related to Excel?

It seems "General" is the only data format to read numbers:

You should do nothing with it.

This looks more like a comment than an actual answer - [answer]

@DarkBee It needs to reserve an answer while the question is not closed yet. :-)

Unsure why you feel the need to "reserve" an answer for questions that are about to be closed. Please read the linked article: TLDR: "Answer well-asked questions"

@DarkBee Often questions close while TS asked for help.
